# Brightness Fn key slow to change N3700 ( I've tried everything! )

Tags: kernel, shortcut-keys, brightness, 16.04

I have an Acer R3-131T with the new Broadwell Intel Pentium N3700.

My brightness works if it is adjusted in the system settings but when I use the combo "fn+brightness key (in this laptop are the arrows keys)" the command is received about six seconds late and sometimes is not received.

I've tried a lot of solution's codes in the grub (acpi= etc..) for brightness and four different linux distros, the new kernel 4.4.6 with Ubuntu 16.04, ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu 15.10 but nothing works.

Searching on the internet I found a command used in Arch for a similar laptop ( Acer Cloudbook: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Acer_Cloudbook ):  " modprobe.blacklist=pinctrl_cherryview " .

I used it in Ubuntu and the brightness works flawlessly! The problem now is the trackpad: it doesn't work anymore, only the touchscreen works.

Sorry for my bad english!

Thanks for any suggestions